# Sort list year (YYYY and YYYY-MM) in swift

Tags: ios, sorting, swift

I'm trying to sort a list that contains values in the format year.

For example:

```
[2020,2013,2014,2001-06,2001-01,1999,2011]
```

and I want to order this way:

```
[1999,2001-01,2001-06,2011,2013,2014,2020]
```

I did some research and found this way to sort a list in Ascendendig order:

```
listYearData.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }`
```

But in this way seems to order only the values of the year (2000,2001,2002), but when he meets the date in this format: "2000-01 2000-03" not the order

**EDIT:**

The result of the code is:

```
[1999,2001-06,2001-01,2011,2013,2014,2020]
```

Comment: Your data is formatted as `yyyy-MM`, not `MM-yyyy`... Also, you're not going to be able to order `1011` in between `2001-06` and `2013`; it's 1000 years prior.

Comment: Your last sentence still seems to indicate you want to include dates using `MM-yyyy` format.

Comment: What's the result you have with your code?

Comment: I have edited with a example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the format of your data, a lexigraphic (alphabetic) sort will do exactly what you're expecting:

```
println("\(dates.sorted(<))")
```

yields:

```
[1999, 2001-01, 2001-06, 2011, 2013, 2014, 2020]
```

This is one of the major advantages to formatting things as YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: but this only works with the data type of character? Why I error: NSString is not subtype of characters

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  This assumes your data is an array of strings, which your answer implies (otherwise 2001-01 would be sorted as 2000)

Comment: I should probably also note that it assumes a roman character set, but again, that's kind of implied by your example.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use regular expression '\d{4}' and '\d{2}' to catch the 'yyyy', 'MM' and then sort it, if it's string.

Comment: Can you get me an example please ?

Comment: @Stephany It looks like you data is format as 'yyyy-MM', you can use David's.